# Как вывести значения массива?

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой, необходимо вывести несколько раз один и тот же элемент массива, один раз получается вывести Red

```
 <?php
 $color = array("Red");
 echo $color[0];
 ?>
```

А я хочу вывести два раза RedRed

Пишу так, но, не работает:

```
 <?php
 $color = array("Red");
 echo $color[0, 0];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $color[0], $color[0];
```

Или

```
 echo $color[0] . $color[0];
```

Или

```
 echo str_repeat($color[0], 2);
```

---

```
$data = ['one', 'two'];
echo implode('', array_map(
    function($index) use ($data) { return $data[$index];}, 
    [0, 0, 1]
)); // oneonetwo
```

Comment: Это я знаю. Мне нужно что-то на подобии [0, 1, 0, 0, 1];

Comment: ну и пиши так:
 echo $color[0] . $color[1] . $color[0] . $color[0] . $color[1];

Comment: А если уж прям красоты хочется, то
$color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
$outputOrder = [0,1,0,0,2,1,0];
foreach($outputOrder as $key) { echo $color[$key] };

Comment: Мне нужен такой принцип, как создают тайловые карты в 2D играх.

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает решение под чертой? Вы можете отображать индексы тайлов в актуальные данные(`array_map`), чего Вам не хватает?